# HighCharts: Adding different type of data to points

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

According to HighChart Api points have several variables:

color dataLabels x, y, drilldown, events... etc

Are there any way to add extra variables to points in order to reach them at javasciprt functions:

Same thing is possible for series...

Example:

PHP

```
array_push($finalArray,array(x=> $date,y => ($total_income - $total_cost), credit => $total_cost, income => $total_income));
...
echo "leagueID: '" . $leagueID ."' ," ; 
echo "data:" ;
echo json_encode($finalArray) . "},";
```

JSON Output

```
{leagueID: '1' ,data:[{"x":1395180000000,"y":85.28,"credit":35,"income":120.28}
```

JavaScript

```
events: {
    click: function() {
        profit_company_change(this.series.options.leagueID);//It is possible, it can find this.series.options.leagueID)
```

JavaScript 2

```
 ...+ '$</b><br/>Tatal credit: <b>' + this.credit +'$</b><br/>Profit: <b>'+ this.y ; // This is not possible because of this.credit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
series:[{
  data:[{
    y:20,
    customParameter: 'loreum ipsum'
   },1,2,3]
}]
```

Then this parameter will be available in the point.options object.

Comment: How can i made a variable without " with json coded array. In addition why it can find "x": but cannot find "cutomParameter":

Comment: The rest of my code rest same; the solution is only;

Just using this **.point.** options.custom

Comment: works fine, thanks. I tried to mean that it(customParameter) can be between ".

I'm suprised because of that: it is working for this.x but not this.customParameter , thanks to answer i realized that it sould be this.point.options.customParameter .